# Extract String Data From DataFrame Column To Separate Columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, jupyter

I have a data frame column that looks like this:

```
df['out_column']

0         Out 0: 0.024 Out 1: 0.005 
1         Out 0: 0.024 Out 1: 0.009 
2         Out 0: 0.024 Out 1: 0.009 
3         Out 0: 0.024 Out 1: 0.01 
4         Out 0: 0.024 Out 1: 0.011           
5         Out 0: 0.017 Out 1: 0.018 
6         Out 0: 0.146 Out 1: 0.081 
7         Out 0: 0.001 Out 1: 0.002 
8         Out 0: 0.022 Out 1: 0.009 
9         Out 0: 0.012 Out 1: 0.008
```

How can I separate the data on this column to create to other column with the values in front of `Out 0:` and `Out 1:`?
The expected outcome is:

```
          col1   col2
0         0.024  0.005 
1         0.024  0.009 
2         0.024  0.009 
3         0.024  0.01 
4         0.024  0.011           
5         0.017  0.018 
6         0.146  0.081 
7         0.001  0.002 
8         0.022  0.009 
9         0.012  0.008
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a regular pattern with `Out 1` and `Out 2`, you can do `str.extract` and looking for anything with `.` several time `*`

```
print(df['out_column'].str.extract('Out 0: (.*) Out 1: (.*)'))
       0      1
0  0.024  0.005
1  0.024  0.009
2  0.024  0.009
3  0.024   0.01
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extractall`:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df['out_column'].str.extractall(
    pat=r'.*?\s+\d+:\s+([\d.]+)').unstack(-1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
                   out_column   col1   col2
0  Out 0: 0.024 Out 1: 0.005   0.024  0.005
1  Out 0: 0.024 Out 1: 0.009   0.024  0.009
2  Out 0: 0.024 Out 1: 0.009   0.024  0.009
3   Out 0: 0.024 Out 1: 0.01   0.024   0.01
4   Out 0: 0.024 Out 1: 0.011  0.024  0.011
5  Out 0: 0.017 Out 1: 0.018   0.017  0.018
6  Out 0: 0.146 Out 1: 0.081   0.146  0.081
7  Out 0: 0.001 Out 1: 0.002   0.001  0.002
8  Out 0: 0.022 Out 1: 0.009   0.022  0.009
9   Out 0: 0.012 Out 1: 0.008  0.012  0.008
```

NOTE: Use `df = df.drop('out_columns', 1)` if requried.